# Any node module by which Java code can be called

Tags: java, node.js, npm

Is there any node module which can call Java code from node.js? My requirement is to call a simple Java application via node. 
Apart from node-java module is there any other modules available in node.js
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create a process using regular shell access:

http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html